# Подписаться на событие которое обрабатывается в классе

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, zipfile

Предположим, есть класс для работы с `zip` архивом:

```
class ArchiveClass
{
    public static void AddFileToArchive(string path, string new_path)
    {
        using(var zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            zip.Password = "123456";
            zip.SaveProgress += SaveProgress;
            zip.AddFile(path);
            zip.Save(new_path);
        }
    }
}
```

Метод `SaveProgress` должен обращаться к контролам формы (лейбл, прогресс бар).

Как будет правильно, изменить у прогресс бара, например, свойство `Value` и `Maximum`?

Я попробовал сделать так:

```
class MyProgressBar
{
    public delegate void ProgressBarEventHandler(ProgressBarEventArgs arg);
    public event ProgressBarEventHandler ProgressBarChanged;

    private int _value;
    public int Val
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            OnProgressBarChange(_value);
        }
    }

    private void OnProgressBarChange(int progress) => ProgressBarChanged?.Invoke(new ProgressBarEventArgs(progress));

    public class ProgressBarEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public int Val { get; }

        public ProgressBarEventArgs(int value) => this.Val = value;
    }
}
```

Но в таком случае, мне приходиться в методе `SaveProgress` создавать новый экземпляр класса `MyProgressBar`, а потом ещё в главной форме создавать опять новый экземпляр класса `MyProgressBar` и подписываться на него...

короче, какая-то "дичь". Может быть как-то из главной формы можно подписаться на изменение `SaveProgress`?..

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком направлении вообще нужно двигаться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно в метод `AddFileToArchive` добавить дополнительный параметр с типом события `SaveProgress`:

```
public static void AddFileToArchive(string path, string new_path,
    SaveProgressEventHandler saveProgress)
{
    ...
    zip.SaveProgress += saveProgress;
    ...
}
```

Где-то, допустим, в главной форме должен метод с такой же сигнатурой:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    void SaveProgress(...)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Его и передаёте в виде делегата:

```
ArchiveClass.AddFileToArchive("path", "newPath", SaveProgress);
```